# How to compare two dates in different zones in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to compare these two dates in different time zones in ruby

Code:

```
if (mydate.to_datetime -
        (120).minutes).to_datetime >
            DateTime.now

puts mydate # 2019-05-30 20:42:34
mydate.to_time # 2019-05-30T20:42:34+00:00
# after subtracting 120 minutes 2019-05-30T18:42:34+00:00
puts DateTime.now # 2019-05-30T20:24:12+05:30
```

I need to subtract 120 minutes from mydate and compare with currentdate.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: I need to compare this two time t1=2019-05-30T19:37:18+00:00 and t2=019-05-30T19:37:30+05:30 , but the thing is that they are in different time zones

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is here. To compare dates in different time zones, you just compare them. It works as normal. The time zones are taken into account during the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

[`Time.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) can handle Time Zones with no issue:

```
2.5.1 :001 > require 'time'
 => true 
2.5.1 :002 > t1 = Time.parse('2019-05-30T19:37:18+00:00')
 => 2019-05-30 19:37:18 +0000 
2.5.1 :003 > t2 = Time.parse('2019-05-30T19:37:30+05:30')
 => 2019-05-30 19:37:30 +0530 
2.5.1 :004 > t1 > t2
 => true 
2.5.1 :005 > t2 > t1
 => false 
2.5.1 :006 > t1 == t2
 => false 
2.5.1 :007 > t1 - t2
 => 19788.0 # result is in seconds, convert to whatever you need
```

Assuming you already have declared these two variables as `DateTime` instances where `t1` is `2019-05-30T19:37:18+00:00` and `t2` is `2019-05-30T19:37:30+05:30`, you can run comparisons directly and get the results in seconds using `.to_time`

```
2.5.1 :009 > t1 > t2
 => true 
2.5.1 :010 > t2 > t1
 => false 
2.5.1 :011 > t1 == t2
 => false
2.5.1 :012 > t1.to_time - t2.to_time
 => 19788.0
```

Comment: I am getting this error : no implicit conversion of DateTime into String

Comment: @WakeUpSid If they're already DateTime variables, you can run `.to_time` on them to do this math. I'll update my answer.

Comment: What’s wrong with doing math directly on `DateTime` instances?

Answer (score 1):

Difference in days:

```
%w[2019-05-30T19:37:18+00:00 2019-05-30T19:37:30+05:30].
  map { |d| DateTime.iso8601(d) }.reduce(:-)
#⇒ (1649/7200)
```

In hours:

```
%w[2019-05-30T19:37:18+00:00 2019-05-30T19:37:30+05:30].
  map { |d| DateTime.iso8601(d) }.reduce(:-) * 24
#⇒ (1649/300)
```

In minutes:

```
%w[2019-05-30T19:37:18+00:00 2019-05-30T19:37:30+05:30].
  map { |d| DateTime.iso8601(d) }.reduce(:-) * 24 * 60
#⇒ (1649/5)
```

The outcome is [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html) to preserve accuracy. One might convert it to integer, float, or decimal.